# Where to find pyOutlook OAuth token?

Tags: python, outlook-2010

I am looking at the documentation of pyOutlook. 
https://pythonhosted.org/pyOutlook/

The very first example is like the following:

```
from pyOutlook import OutlookAccount
account_one = OutlookAccount('token 1')
account_two = OutlookAccount('token 2')
```

And as I checked, the definition for the token is **A string OAuth token from Outlook allowing access to a user’s account"**

I have no experience with this so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I only know a little about OAuth.  Normally, you go through a few steps before you finally end up with this token.  Those steps are what are happening in your browser when you switch over to a Google page and give approval to use your Google creds, etc.  In the end, you get a "bearer token".  This token is then passed with each request to the server.

Comment: I have recently used just the tail end of this scheme where I was just given the "bearer token" to connect to a partner's web API.  So didn't have to do all the other stuff.  I don't know if that's what's going on here, but if you need a single value to use with OAuth, that sounds like the "bearer token"...the last step in OAuth.  With all that said, you need to figure out how to come up with that token.  If you're talking about a corporate mail system, maybe your IT folks could help you get this token.  Or maybe you can get it from a URL after once going through a full OAuth setup.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I am trying to get it for my personal gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/

Then log in with your outlook credentials ("Authorize using your own account")

And press "Get Tokens"

"Access Token" is the one you will want to use (beware they only last for an hour)

Comment: The link is not working anymore.